# PHP Cassandra random busy I/O threads, request timed out

Tags: php, cassandra

I have a 3 node Cassandra v3.11.4 cluster. Replication factor = 3 and around 70GB data in each cluster.

Node hardware: m5.2xlarge (8 vCPU, 32 GB RAM, 500GB SSD)

Some YAML values:

```
num_tokens: 256
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
```

PHP connection from load balanced compute engines:

```
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()->withPort(PORT)->withDefaultConsistency(Cassandra::CONSISTENCY_LOCAL_QUORUM)->withContactPoints(HOST_VAL)->withIOThreads(5)->withCredentials(CASS_USER, CASS_PASS)->build();
$session = $cluster->connect(KEYSPACE);
$statement = $session->prepare($query);
$stmt = $session->execute($statement, ['arguments' => $bindParams]);
```

The Cassandra service runs smoothly for most of the time but for 5-10 minutes every 5-6 hours it starts giving errors from PHP operations:

`Cassandra\Exception\RuntimeException: All connections on all I/O threads are busy`

`Cassandra\Exception\RuntimeException: All hosts in current policy attempted and were either unavailable or failed`

`Cassandra\Exception\TimeoutException: Request timed out`

I am guessing the issue is with PHP Connections either stalling Cassandra nodes or generating too many connections.

Please help me where to look for possible reasons or if there is any `SHOW PROCESSLIST` like command to monitor current connections like in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors indicate that the nodes are getting overloaded and become unresponsive leading to the `TimeoutException` -- the replicas don't respond to the coordinator within the request timeout.

When nodes are busy, the requests queue up waiting to be served. There comes a point when the queues reach the maximum size and any new requests from the client are no longer queued.

Check for long GCs which are indicative of nodes being overloaded. Correlate those times with the amount of read/write traffic from your application (you'll get these metrics from your app monitoring).

My guess is that your application doesn't have a smooth amount of traffic but instead is peaking every few hours. It is during app traffic peaks that the cluster gets overloaded. If this is the case, you need to size your cluster to cope with the peak traffic by adding more nodes. Cheers!

Comment: Hey Erick! Thanks for the help. I checked logs and the entries are similar to this: ```Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.04s, Stopping threads took: 0.0001s. Heap before GC invocations=10582 (full 95). par new generation total 737280K, used 729652K. eden space 655360K, 100% used. from space 81920K, 90% used. to space 81920K, 0% used. GC (Allocation Failure). Heap after GC invocations=10583 (full 95)```. Also, the nodes CPU usage when the timeout was happening was around 25% for each node. Is it possible that C* is not able to fully utilize the node hardware?

Comment: It's really hard to know without looking at your cluster's diagnostics. You'll need to review the logs on the Cassandra nodes yourself to figure out what the problem is. Cheers!